# LO-TO Splitting and Group Theory

Tags: symmetry, phonons, phonon-dispersion

I am curious whether or not there is a connection between the group theoretical assignment of phonon modes and LO-TO splitting. For example, is it true that the frequency of a gerade mode will depend on the direction of approach to $\Gamma$ in reciprocal space? Conversely, is the frequency of an ungerade mode independent of the direction of approach?

Forgive my lack of group theory understanding if this is a silly question.

Thank you,

CW279

Comment: I gave my +1 yesterday, but are you asking 1 question or 2? Please ask only 1 question in each post.

Comment: Apologies - I've removed the edit.

Comment: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5